# Primary Key field needs to be filled with UUID in QGIS before insert

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a postgres database with a postGIS extension. Some of the fields in the database tables are primary keys that are automatically being generated either with a UUID genarator or based on another column. Now, within a postgres/SQL IDE with a 'before insert on' trigger function this is no problem because it is generating the UUID before the insert.

However, I want to achieve the same within QGIS. But because of the NOT NULL characteristic of the PK I can't leave this field empty and thus not being able to save it. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to use a dummy default UUID? The value would be overwritten by your trigger

Comment: @JGH good idea, but most of these fields are referencing UUID values from other tables via foreign keys. I can't insert random UUID's, it will error that it can't be found in the parent table.

Comment: Does the UUID field need to be PK or could it be another unique field?

Comment: @user30184 it could be another I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to

1. **proxy your DDLs through a 'working' *View*** having an `INSTEAD OF`
   trigger in place:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW <main_table>_view AS (
     SELECT <uuid>,
            <link>,
            ...,
            geom::GEOMETRY(<TYPE>, <SRID>)     -- explicitly forcing registration of the geom column
     FROM   <main_table>
   );


   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION <main_table>_view_insert_function()
   RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS
     $$
     BEGIN
       SELECT fk.<uuid>
       FROM   <fk_table> AS fk
       WHERE  fk.<link> = NEW.<link>
       INTO   NEW.id
       ;

       INSERT INTO <main_table>
         VALUES (NEW.*)
       ;
     END;
     $$
   ;

   CREATE TRIGGER <main_table>_view_insert_trigger
     INSTEAD OF INSERT
     ON <main_table>
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE FUNCTION <main_table>_view_insert_function()
   ;
   ```
2. **deactivate `Enforce not null constraint.`** in QGIS:

   ```
   <Layer properties> | Attributes Form | Available Widgets | Fields | <uuid>
   ```

   While the field is still alarmingly red then, the `OK` button is active.

The idea is to only ever load and work with that *View* in QGIS; this allows for plenty other things in terms of access control and data quality validation. `UPDATES` and `DELETES` should work without any triggers, since the *View* itself is *updateable*.

---

**Note:**

You will want to add

```
WHEN (NEW.<uuid> IS NULL)
```

to all `BEFORE INSERT` trigger (or add the respective filter in the function itself if this trigger does more complex data manipulation) if you need to keep them along with the working *View*, to remove it from the trigger chain when inserting via the *View*. While it does no harm, it will essentially duplicate the operation.

Alternatively, you can rewrite the *View*s trigger function to explicitly insert into all *but* the PK column, and have the `BEFORE INSERT` trigger handle the case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION <main_table>_view_insert_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS
  $$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO <main_table>(<link>, ..., geom)
      VALUES (NEW.<link>, ..., NEW.geom)
    ;
  END;
  $$
;
```

Personally, I'd go the non-chaining way, as

- you only want to fire that `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on missing `<uuid>` values anyways (except it does more complex insertion logic, of course)
- trigger chains add overhead, and can become hard to debug